# Spring form binding to List inside c:forEach not working in Websphere 7

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, websphere-7

I am using the below JSP tags in my webapplication (Spring MVC), here command object is List, this code is running fine in Tomcat, JBoss, Weblogic. But failing in Websphere 7.

```
<form:form>
    <c:forEach items="${Items.itemList}" var="item" varStatus="status" >
       <form:input path="itemList[${status.index}].name" />
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

When we access this JSP, getting below error in Websphere 7 application server. Can anybody come across this kind of issue with Websphere.

`org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'itemList[0]' of bean class [com.xxx.yyy.zzz.itemList]: Bean property 'itemList[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

Form backing bean:

```
public class Items {

private List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

public List<Item> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public void setItemList(List<Item> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}
}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {
private String id;
private String name;
private String type;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="showItems",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showItems(ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    Items items = getAllItems();
    model.addAttribute("Items", items) ;
    return "ItemList";
}
```

Comment: please notice ` is not readable or has an invalid getter method:`

Comment: Updated the question with proper class name in error message. The same is working fine in all other app servers, failed in Websphere. here the issue with index we used to represent Object from the list. The getter method is available, it should access like itemList[0].getName(). It is treating itemList[0] as object in Websphere.

Comment: try <form:input path="item[${status.count}].name" />

Comment: Here item is single Object, it is not a List to access with index, getting below error now with this change. `Invalid property 'item[1]' of bean class [com.xxx.yyy.zzz.Items]`

Comment: Can you update the post with the form backing bean and the controller method that renders the view?

Comment: Updated post with form backing bean and controller method.